# Advice on pentesting web applications?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test

A year ago I started to learn some things about hacking websites but in an incorrect/unstructured way. That's why I decided to start over at zero, and that's why I'm here.

What's the things that I should know first in the field of pentesting web applications?

Comment: you may want to be a bit more precise in your question. are you looking to gain experience in pentesting general, pentesting of web applications, organizational security, ... ?

Comment: pentesting of web applications

Comment: Please ask a more accurate question. Otherwise this post is offtopic.

Answer (score 4):

As you are already on Security Stack Exchange page:

- locate a string `Questions` on this page and click on it
- on a newly opened page locate a string `Votes` and click on it

  (this will open a page with links to questions sorted from the one that received most votes to the least)
- click on each one and read carefully the question and answer, think about what you read, and follow links if they are included

  (proceed until about the question with vote count 25)
- in the meantime leave open tabs with questions that dealt with area that you were most interested in and click on grey boxes displayed under a question (they are called tags)
- this time (in your intended area) don't stop on 25+ score questions, but read each and every single one, also those with negative score

This will give you a brief introduction.